# If a sequence $f_{n}\neq0$ converges uniformly and $\frac{1}{f_{n}}$ converges pointwise then it also converges uniformly

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have this question I'm unable to solve (you need to prove this or give a counterexample:

If a sequence $f_{n}\neq0$ ($f_{n}\left(x\right)\neq0,\forall n\geq N\in\mathbb{N}$ for some N) converges uniformly and $\frac{1}{f_{n}}$ converges pointwise then it also converges uniformly.

I tried proving $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{1}{f_{n}\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}\right|=0$$ but it didn't work. I tried looking at function of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ but $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}=n$ doesn't converge. I tried looking at $$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & x\leq\frac{1}{n}\\
0 & x>\frac{1}{n}
\end{cases}$$ but it doesn't fit the demand of $f_{n}\neq0$.

So I wasn't able to prove nor provide a counterexample

Comment: What is the definition set of the sequence of maps?

Comment: You speak about series of functions or sequence ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah sequence, I will change the title

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net If I understand you question correctly there is no given set in the question.

Comment: Can't you just let $f_n(x)=1$ if $x>\frac{1}{n}$? (From your example, it seems that your domain is $(0,\infty)$, but you should state this explicitly in your question.)

Comment: For uniform convergence of $1/f_n$ you would need more conditions like a compact domain.  Also you need conditions that $f(x) \neq 0$.  It is not enough that $f_n(x) \neq 0$ since we could have $f_n(x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{n}$ where $f_n(x) \to f(x) =\frac{1}{x}$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ and $\frac{1}{f_n(x)} \to x$ pointwise.

The uniform convergence of $f_n$ is obvious since $\left|f_n(x)  - f(x)\right| = \frac{1}{n}$. Choosing any $N(\epsilon) > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| <\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{N(\epsilon)}< \epsilon$  for all $n > N(\epsilon)$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$.

However,

$$\left|\frac{1}{f_n(x)}- \frac{1}{f(x)} \right|= \left|\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{n}}- x\right|= \frac{\frac{x}{n}}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{n}} =\frac{x^2}{n + x},$$

and the convergence of $\frac{1}{f_n}$ is not uniform on $(0,\infty)$ since

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\frac{1}{f_n(x)}- \frac{1}{f(x)} \right| = \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\frac{x^2}{n + x}\geqslant \frac{n^2}{n+ n}= \frac{n}{2}\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow+\infty \neq 0 $$